# bs-webapi - How to loop over Dom.nodeList?

Tags: reason, bucklescript, bs-webapi

The following won't work since sides is a `Dom.nodeList` and `DomTokenList.forEach` expects a `Dom.domTokenList`.

```
open Bs_webapi.Dom;

external length : Dom.nodeList => int = "" [@@bs.get];

let sides = Document.querySelectorAll "#carousel > figure" document;

DomTokenList.forEach (fun item _ => print_endline item) (sides);
```

Comment: You should try to be a bit more patient and avoid unnecessary cross-posting like this. It had already been answered on Discord when you posted this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paraphrased from the Reason Discord, courtesy of @anmonteiro:

```
Js.Array.forEach Js.log (NodeList.toArray sides);
```

Here is an example of how to `setAttribute` for each element in a `NodeList`.  Note, `Element.ofNode` can be used to convert a `Dom.node` to `option Dom.element`.

```
open Bs_webapi.Dom;

external length : Dom.nodeList => int = "" [@@bs.get];

let sides = Document.querySelectorAll "#carousel > figure" document;

Js.Array.forEachi
  (fun side index =>
    switch (Element.ofNode side) {
    | Some element =>
      Element.setAttribute "style" "some style here" element
    | None => ()
    }
  )
  (NodeList.toArray sides)
```

https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js_array.html#VALforEach